# C# Replace multiple spaces in a string with newline

Tags: c#, regex, replace, newline, spaces

This questioned has been asked before in regard to other languages but I could't find anything on using regex or any other algorithm to solve this in C#.

For example:

> Photosynthesis maintains atmospheric oxygen levels and supplies all of
>   the organic compounds and most of the energy necessary for life on
>   Earth. Most cases,   oxygen is also released as a waste product. **(((((THIS SERIES OF SPACES HERE THAT SUGGEST THE END OF A PARAGRAPH))))**
>   Although photosynthesis is performed differently by different
>   species, the process always begins when energy from light is absorbed
>   by proteins called reaction centers that contain green chlorophyll
>   pigments.

should be formatted as:

> Photosynthesis maintains atmospheric oxygen levels and supplies all of
>   the organic compounds and most of the energy necessary for life on
>   Earth.
>
> Although photosynthesis is performed differently by different species,
>   the process always begins when energy from light is absorbed by
>   proteins called reaction centers that contain green chlorophyll
>   pigments.

How do I get this done?

Comment: What about `Most cases, oxygen is also released as a waste product.` ? :)

Comment: I want the paragraph to be separated by a new line at the end of that line sir :) @L.B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var SpacedText = "Some sample text.           This should be a new paragraph."

var NewlineText = Regex.Replace(SpacedText , @"\s{2,}", Environment.NewLine);
```

Change the 2 in the regex for however many spaces you want it to break on.

Environment.NewLine can be replaced with whatever newline delimiter you need (`<br />` for html, or any listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)).

Comment: This sort of does the trick :D but how do I change the regex code so that it breaks after detecting 4+ amounts of spaces instead of detecting 'exactly' 4 spaces?

Comment: If you played around with the regex, you'll find the number specifies only the minimum number of spaces to break on. Change the 2 to a 4 and you're away.

Answer (score 0):

The best guess that I can think of is to match the end of sentence . and possible trailing whitespace, before also end of line, and replace it with . and carriage return/linefeed.

In this case the regex would be

```
 \.\s*[\r\n]+
```

http://regex101.com/r/cU2tF9/1